# Seeking correct range of cv values for WorldClim BIO4 historic and BIO4 RCP 2.6

Tags: temperature

WorldClim BIO4 stated as BIO4 = Temperature Seasonality (standard deviation ×100)
https://www.worldclim.org/data/index.html
The source file for **historic** climate shows across the globe a range of 0 to 2,000 or so
The source file for **future** climate RCP2.6 mean averaged over GCMS: (CN GF GS HE MI) is showing a range of 0 to 20,000

Please is there an amending factor required for the future climate values ?
(They are order of magnitude different x 10.)
Thank you

[image: BIO4 HISTORIC]
[image: BIO4 RCP 2.6]